# Как установить модуль zram в linux систему?

Tags: linux, debian

У меня есть хост debian 9, версия linux `4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`.

Я хотел включить на этом хосте zram, но столкнулся с ошибкой:

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module zram not found.
Feb  8 08:42:23 ks1 zram[27122]: modprobe: FATAL: Module zram not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

Kernel-модуля в системе нет.
Я проверил директорию `/lib/modules/4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/kernel`, а она вообще пустая. Хотя на других моих хостах там куча модулей.

Я взял с другого хоста модуль `zram.ko`. Закинул его по пути `/lib/modules/4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/kernel/drivers/block/zram/zram.ko`. Добавил имя модуля `zram` в `/etc/modules`. Но модуль не заработал, мне написало ошибку:

```
Feb  8 09:30:03 ks1 zram[3841]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zram': Exec format error
Feb  8 09:30:03 ks1 kernel: zram: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Как мне установить модуль `zram`?

---

Дополнение к вопросу №1.

Я пытался установить модуль zram.

1. Я скачал исходники linux https://www.kernel.org/.
   В моем случае я скачал свою версию https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.229.tar.gz.
2. Распаковываем исходники, я это сделал в директорию `/usr/src/linux-4.19.229`
3. Заходим в директорию с модулем zram `/usr/src/linux-4.19.229/drivers/block/zram`.
4. Редактируем файл `Makefile`.
5. Надо в файл `Makefile` добавить в конец такой текст:

```
obj-m = zram.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

6. После этого запускаем компиляцию командой `make`.
7. После компиляции будет создан файл `/usr/src/linux-4.19.229/drivers/block/zram/zram.ko`.
8. Этот файл надо переместить в директорию `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/`.
   В моем случае я его переместил по пути `/lib/modules/4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64/kernel/drivers/block/zram/zram.ko`.
9. Теперь пишем эту команду `depmod -a`, чтобы обновить список модулей.
10. Теперь я пробую загрузить модуль командой `modprobe zram`.
    И мне выводит ошибку:

```
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_unmap_object (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_pool_stats (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_get_total_pages (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_create_pool (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_free (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_compact (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_malloc (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_destroy_pool (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_map_object (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 kernel: zram: Unknown symbol zs_huge_class_size (err -2)
Feb 11 16:17:27 ks1 zram[3328]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zram': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Пока что на этом моменте я застрял.

Я действовал по этой инструкции: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html

Comment: Судя по https://repology.org/project/zram-tools/versions - тебе надо апаться.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install -y zram-config`

Если не ругается, то у вас уже есть SWAP в виде zRAM. Ну а если ругается, то надо поставить "linux-image-generic" и перезагрузится, после чего снова попробовать поставить "zram-config":

запустить сервис вручную:
`systemctl start zram-config`

проверить так: `sudo swapon -s`

Или вот еще информация: https://losst.ru/nastrojka-zram-v-linux

Comment: Я смог только установить `linux-image-4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`. Ребутнул хост. Но установить `zram-config` не могу `E: Unable to locate package zram-config`. Модуль zram не появился `modinfo: ERROR: Module zram not found.`.

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос попыткой скомпилировать модуль.